# Angular ngIf not showing then or else

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I tried to use ngIf but nothing shows.
The countdown should show when finished = false, and if finished = true, the button should show.

```
<div *ngIf="!finished; then thenCountdown else elseButton">jo ho ho</div>
<!-- COUNTDOWN -->
<ng-template #thenCountdown>
    <div id="countdown">
        finished is false
        <countdown [config]="{ stopTime: 1561901216000 }" (finished)isFinished()>
            $!d!:$!h!:$!m!:$!s!
        </countdown>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<!-- BUTTON -->
<ng-template #elseButton>
    <div>
        finished is true
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: If you remove the `countdown` part, does it work?

Comment: yes, if I remove the countdown part it works

Comment: The problem is because the finished variable is used in the countdown tag, the complete ngIf code does not work.

Comment: I think you need an `=` here: `(finished)isFinished()`

Comment: So: the problem is in the countdown, not in the ngIf

Comment: It should be `(finished)="isFinished()"` not `(finished)isFinished()`

Comment: Which is your problem: nothing is shown or "finished is true" is shown?

Comment: Do you have a variable in your `.ts` file `public finished = false;` and you update it in the function `isFinished() { this.finished = true;}`?

Comment: please can you make this app in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fixxks) works to me. I added

```
  public finished = false;

  public isFinished() {
    this.finished = true;
  }
```

I imported the `CountdownModule` and I fixed the `=` sign.

I hope it helps.

Comment: or: toggleFinished() { this.finished = !finished }

Comment: This will not work. `(finished)=isFinished()` must be changed to `(finished)="isFinished()"`

Comment: Hi! In stackblitz it works but you're right, `"isFinished()"` should be placed inside quotation marks. So, problem solved?

Comment: Did the solution work for you? If it did, could you please accept the answer? If not, which problem do you have still?